# Hiding Table Columns With JQuery

Tags: jquery, optimization, performance

This method is used to hide columns in a table based on a collection of metadata json objects. There is an object per column in the table. Currently on a table that has ~500 rows and ~15 columns with 6 being hidden this method takes ~2 seconds to execute.

I am attempting to optimize it to be faster. Any suggestions?

```
function hideHiddenColumns() {
  if (tableMetaData.length) {
    for (var index = 0; index < tableMetaData.length; index++) {
      var item = tableMetaData[index];
      if (!item.DisplayFlag) {
        $table.find('th:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + '), td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where `$table` comes from, but how about good old DOM instead of a complex jQuery selector:

```
$table.each( function() {
  var rows = this.rows;
  var rowCount = rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].cells;
    if (cells.length > index) {
      $(cells[index]).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Obviously this implies that no merged cells exist in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Go with plain JS, jsust as Tomalak suggested. You can also optimize the `for` loop with `while`:

```
var item, i = tableMetaData.length;
while (i--) {
  item = tableMetaData[i];
  // do what's gotta be done
}
```

The reversed `while` loop used to be by far the fastest looping structure. With the recent improvements in latest JS engines the difference is not that big anymore though

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to show and hide columns of a HTML table: [jQuery - Tables - Show and Hide Columns](http://tokenposts.blogspot.com/2011/05/jquery-tables-show-and-hide-columns.html)